# HERE Satelite Map API returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: here-api

When I send a GET request for `satellite.day` to the HERE Satellite Map API, I get a 400 error.

`https://1.aerial.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/6/30/25/256/png8?apiKey=my-api-key`

I use the URL as provided in [the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/map-tile/map-tile-satellite).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL on the example page is outdated. It worked with this URL:

`https://1.aerial.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/6/30/25/256/png8?apiKey=my-api-key`